# Display of non iso characters in SQL query results

Tags: sql, r, rstudio

Trying to solve issue with wrong display of national characters (Polish) in results of query to MS SQL database.

The script is pretty standard

First the definnition connection object

```
library(DBI)    
db.conn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
    Driver = "SQL Server Native Client 11.0", 
    Server = "10.0.0.100",
    Port = 1433,
    Database = "DB",
    UID    = "user",
    PWD    = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password"),
    encoding = "latin1"
)
```

then SQL statement

```
db_sql = "    
    select
        *
    from test
    where active = 'ACTIVE'
    order by name_id"
```

Then execution of SQL

```
db_query <- dbSendQuery(db.conn, db_sql)
db_data <- dbFetch(db_query)
```

or

```
db_data <- dbGetQuery(db.conn, db_sql)
```

It does not matter whether in connection object definition I use "latin1", "windows-1250" or "utf-8" parameter for encoding parameter the results are always the same

Strings with U+009C or similar

It also does not matter what codepage I select in RStudio Global options.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

First it is necessary to change locale to Polish

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "Polish")
```

Then set proper encoding in

```
DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc()
...
encoding = "windows-1250"
```

and voilla, working.